# Checking value of HTML input issues

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have this HTML:

```
<input type="number" id="num">
<input type="submit" onclick="test()">
```

and this script:

```
function test() {
    var num = document.getElementById("num").value;
    alert(num === 1);
```

so why do I get `false` when I enter 1 as my input?

If I try `alert(num - 1 === 0);` instead of `alert(num === 1);` I get `true`. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values of form controls are always strings (`type="number"` just asks the browser to enforce that the string contains a number). You can convert it to a number with `+`, `parseInt`, or `parseFloat`. You could also compare to `"1"` instead of `1`.

If you [subtract](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.2) a number from a string, JavaScript will convert the string to a number before performing the subtraction, and then the result will evaluate as a number.

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing it to a string.

```
function test() {
    var num = document.getElementById("num").value;
    alert(num === "1");
```

The === operator is much stricter and requires the compared values to be of both equal value and type. In this case you are comparing a string to a number.

Answer (score 0):

Quentin's answer is correct, but just to add to it:

You can check if it is 1 using lazy equals (I.e. no type checking.) `num == 1`

Or, just compare against a string: `num === "1"`